# How do you create a menu folder in a red folder

Tags: android, xml

how do you create a res/menu folder with a main.xml when a res/layout has a main.xml file

Comment: Hi Munashe, were there any restrictions while creating? If so? please share.

Answer (score 0):

1. In the project tab of left pane, select the res folder and Control+click to open context menu. Then, **New > Android Resouce Directory**.

[image: screenshot 1]

2. Just name it **menu** for the directory name. And click ok.

[image: screenshot 2]

3. Now you got res/menu, select it and Control+click to open context menu. Then, **New > Menu Resource File**.

[image: screenshot 3]

4. Input your menu resource file's name (ex. main).

[image: screenshot 4]

5. At last you can get res/menu/main.xml.

[image: screenshot 5]